# Why not calling RXJS unsubscribe appears to cause a memory leak in Java application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rxjs, memory-leaks

At my work, I was doing some operational maintenance in production and I noticed one of our Java/Spring Boot/Hibernate applications was using over 4GB of memory while idle. I immediately suspected that something was amiss, as other developers on the team had never seen this behavior before. I was able to replicate the issue in our test environment and used VisualVM to inspect the application's resources. Turns out there were several memory leaks.

Our frontend is using Angular with RxJS to subscribe to methods that wrap an HTTP request made by Angular's HttpClient. After cross checking calls frontend was making with the Java objects that were consuming the most memory, I found there was no unsubscribe--even in ngOnDestroy--for some of the subscriptions. Adding an unsubscribe immediately caused Java to garbage collect those objects.

I understand not calling unsubscribe can cause a memory leak. But what I don't understand is why this causes a memory leak in Java, particularly a standard REST API application. I've searched for an answer but every example I've found only discusses the relationship between subscribe and unsubscribe. Has anyone encountered this issue before or can someone offer an explanation? In case it's something version specific, I've listed the core technologies we're using with their versions below:

- Java 13
- Spring Boot (2.6.6)
- Hibernate ORM (5.6.7.Final)
- Angular 9 (9.1.0)
- RxJS (6.5.4)

Comment: most likely the requests in question are returning streaming results  which means until the server "ends" the stream or the UI unsubscribes then the server infrastructure required to process that request will be pinned by the open connection.  Check your Java code for StreamingResponseBody usage or some other library like WebFlux to see if this is the cause.  Also you can use Chrome devtools on the app and monitor the network tab for requests that never finish to help find the ones that are streaming